# Strings’ Number of Characters & Alphabetical Order

Tags: c, string

Develop a C program to perform the following:

- Create two 1-D character arrays of 25 elements named first and second.
- Ask the user to input two strings and store them in the arrays first and second.
- Pass both arrays to a function named countChars, which counts and prints the number of characters in each string.
- Pass both arrays to another function named order, which determines and returns a result that shows which string precedes the other in alphabetical order. When the returned result is received by the main function, it prints a message to show their order. For example, if the first string is “green” and the second is “white”, the function determines that green is before white in alphabetical order. The main function prints a statement that says: 
  “ In alphabetical order, \green\ is before \white\ ”.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char first[25], second[25];
  int length1, length2;
  printf("Enter the first and the second string: ");
  scanf("%s %s", first, second);
  length1 = strlen(first);
  length2 = strlen(second);
  order(first, second);
  return 0;
}

int order(char *first, char *second) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; first[i] && second[i] && first[i] == second[i]; i++)
    if (first[i] && second[i]) {
      return 1;
    } else
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What do you have?  Show us your code.  Where is your problem?  Please use proper formatting of your question.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

int main(){

  char first[25],second[25];

    int length1, length2;

    printf("Enter the first and the second string: ");

    scanf("%s %s",first,second);

    length1 = strlen(first);
    length2 = strlen(second);
:( :(

Comment: guys im new to this site iam sorry , i just don't know how to sort 2 strings in alphabetical order , i can for 1 string but not 2

Comment: @AmerSyouri it is your homework not ours.

Comment: @AmerSyouri - `edit` and add your code to the the bottom of the question (indent each line by 4-spaces so it formats as code) and include any errors or problems in the output you get. Then we will all be able to help (e.g. you provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @P__J__ chill please , im looking for help ... not a full solution

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin like this ?

Comment: Yes, like that after I edited. (click edit again, look at the formatting, then click cancel if you like) And.. aren't you supposed to use `countChars` instead of `strlen`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you so much ,

 im only confused from the fourth step and looking for help , not a full solution .

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yea  thank you, my bad

Comment: Say you have a function `int inorder (char *first, char *second) {...}` where you pass `first` and `second` to the function. You check each char in `first` and `second` against each other until you hit a difference or run out of chars. (figure out which sorts before the other), then return `1` if they are sorted, or return `0` if not. Give it a shot, e.g. `int i; for (i = 0; first[i] && second[i] && first[i] == second[i]; i++) {}` now evaluate `if (first[i] && second[i]) { /* check which is greater */ }` now handle the case where you ran out of chars.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin check my edit please , shouldnt i use     bool function ?

Comment: Let's use `int inorder (char *a, char *b)` to shorten things. First, scan forward in both strings to find the first character where they differ, e.g. `for (i = 0; a[i] && b[i] && a[i] == b[i]; i++) {}`, now cover all cases `if (!a[i] && !b[i])` both out of chars and same, return 1, `else if (!a[i] && b[i])`, `a` ran out first, return 1 (it sorts before b), `else if (!b[i] && a[i])` return 0 (b sorts before a), `else if (a[i] < b[i])` chars remain, a sorts before b, and finally `else return 0;` b sorts before a. (no need for bool)

Comment: Also note, you would generally want to return `-1` if `a` sorts before `b`, return `0` if `a` is the same as `b` and return `1` if `b` sorts before `a` to be consistent with `strcmp`, but for your question, equality wasn't asked for. (but the approach can be the same, just alter what is returned)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of `order()`  matches the functionality of `strcmp()`.

Thus a quick solution for `order()` is

```
int order(char *first, char *second) {
  return strcmp(first, second);
}
```

---

Yet perhaps the goal is to [re-invent the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel).

As [@David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894676/strings-number-of-characters-alphabetical-order#comment94635668_53894676) commented, run down the strings looking for a difference.

Then use a common C idiom of `(a > b) - (a < b)` for the compare.  This avoids all overflow issues - even though they are not likely when the type is `char`.

```
// return 0 on match
// return 1: first > second
// return -1: first < second
int order(char *first, char *second) {
  while (*first && *second && *first == *second) {
    first++;
    second++;
  }
  return (*first > *second) - (*first < *second);
}
```

---

Some improvements:

- Use `const` to allow the function calls with `const char *` as well as `char *` arguments.
- No need to test `*first` and `*second`.
- Slightly more efficient to test the more likely mis-match first.
- Liberal use of `()` may aid in clearly understanding code.
- Compare as `unsigned char`.  `str...()` functions assess the characters as `unsigned char`, even if `char` is *signed* .  This makes a difference when ordering strings with negative characters, something unlikely with OP's data.

.

```
int order_alt(const char *first, const char *second) {
  while ((*first == *second) && *first) {
    first++;
    second++;
  }
  return ((unsigned char)*first > (unsigned char)*second) - 
         ((unsigned char)*first < (unsigned char)*second);
}
```

Comment: The main function prints a statement that says: “ In alphabetical order, e.g. \green\ is before \white\ ”.
what would the statement look like ?

Comment: @AmerSyouri `int compare_result = order(first, second); if (compare_result < 0) do_this else do_that;`

Comment: 100/100 , thank you so much <3